# how can i create Db table using ForiegnKey relationship in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Halo i'm working on creating multiple DB table using foreignKey but i'm  having some error hoping anyone can help out, below is my code & the error msg

###models.py file

```
 class SchoolVideo(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='school_video')
    intro_video = models.FileField(
        upload_to='assets/videos', blank=True, null=True)
```

###serializer file

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SchoolVideo
        fields = ('intro_video',)

        def create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'user' in validated_data:
                user = validated_data.pop('user')
            else:
                user = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
            school_video = SchoolVideo.objects.update_or_create(
                user=user, defaults=validated_data
            )
            return school_video
```

###API VIEW

```
class SchoolVideoAPi(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    queryset = SchoolVideo.objects.all()
    permission_class = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=request.data, instance=request.user.profile.school_video
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data,
            message='Video successfully Uploaded',
            status=status.HTTPS_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers,
        )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.user.profile)

        serializer.save(user=self.request.user.profile)
```

this is the traceback/err message i'm getting
##err traceback

```
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/sch-market/schoolDetail/apiviews.py", line 117, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/sch-market/schoolDetail/apiviews.py", line 128, in perform_create
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user.profile)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 445, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 483, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "<CustomUser: abc@xyz.com>": "SchoolVideo.school" must be a "Profile" instance.
```

[[image]][1[image: ]]

can anyone help out

Answer (score 0):

The error is  caused by this line:

```
instance=request.user.profile.school_video
```

As the error says, you are passing `school_video` as an instance, but it is failing because it is a `RelatedManager`. Just filter out which `school_video` you need to fix this.

For example:

```
instance=request.user.profile.school_video.first()
```

or

```
instance=request.user.profile.school_video.filter(<your filters).first()
```

Just making sure your queryset returns only one object.

Also next time, please try to avoid adding images for code and errors and just put them as text in the question.

Comment: thanks for the response but when i did this 

```instance=request.user.profile.school_video.filter(id=request.user.profile.id).first())```



i'm getting this err 


```/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__raise ValueError(ValueError: Cannot assign "<CustomUser: abc@xyz.com>":"SchoolVideo.school" must be a "Profile" instance.```

Comment: You are filtering `school_video` with a `Profile` id causing this error. You need to filter `school_video` with a `SchoolVideo` id

Comment: `request.user.profile.school_video.filter(id=request.user.profile.id)`-- here `request.user.profile.id` cannot be used against `school_video.filter(id=`

Comment: In the meantime try it with `school_video.first()` and see if it works

Comment: i've tried this & now i'm getting this err ```ValueError: Cannot assign "<CustomUser: abc@xyz.com>": "SchoolVideo.school" must be a "Profile" instance.```

Comment: Can you paste the whole traceback in the question? I'm suspecting its coming from the serializer create but don't want to guess

Comment: Can you show the update part of the serializer. Or if possible, the whole serializer

Comment: that the whole serializer